# Creating INNER Joins with IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join three tables using and inner join and have the contents of one change colour if an e-mail has been sent.

Below is my query

```
SELECT IIF(COUNT Holdsent.job)>0, #STD, #RED) AS Colour, jobs.job, jobs.jobstatus, jobs.client, jobs.logdate
FROM jobs INNER JOIN clients ON clients.client = jobs.client INNER JOIN holdsent ON holdsent.job = jobs.job
WHERE (jobs.jobstatus = 'HOLD' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'CLIHOLD')
```

Below is the error I receive

> Expected lexical element not found: (missing ( in aggregate function
>   [Parsing Expression (column1 in the SELECT clause)] -- Location of
>   error in the SQL statement is:1 SELECT IIF(COUNT
>   Holdsent.job)>0,#STD, #RED) AS COLOUR,jobs.job,
>   jobs.jobstatus,jobs.client,jobs.logdate FROM jobs INNER JOIN clients
>   ON clients.client = jobs.client INNER JOIN holdsent ON holdsent.job =
>   jobs.job  WHERE (jobs.jobstatus = 'HOLD' OR jobs.jobstatus =
>   'CLIHOLD')

I am new to SQL and can do basic queries, but am not clear on IIF.   Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff From error message I would say it's MS Sql Server...

Comment: Sorry we are using SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didnt mock up test tables for this, but I think you want to subquery against your `holdsent` table to get the count value into the main query, then use three parameters in your [IIF() function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).  I didnt make a test case, but I think this will suit your needs:

```
SELECT      IIF((isnull(holdsentCount.jobCount,0)>0, #STD, #RED) AS Colour
            , jobs.job
            , jobs.jobstatus
            , jobs.client
            , jobs.logdate
FROM        jobs 
JOIN        clients 
ON          clients.client = jobs.client 
LEFT JOIN   (select     holdsent.job
                        , count(*) as jobCount 
            from        holdsent 
            group by    holdsent.job ) as holdsentCount
ON          holdsentCount.job = jobs.job
WHERE       (jobs.jobstatus = 'HOLD' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'CLIHOLD')
```

Also, wrap the `holdsentCount.jobCount` with isnull() so that it returns 0 if it isn't returned in the subquery.

EDIT: I dont know what '#STD' or '#RED' are so I left them as-is.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

`iif` is a special function from MS Access, which SQL Server has started supporting with the most recent version.  The correct SQL form is the `case` statement.  An improved version of your query, written in standard SQL, is:

```
SELECT (case when COUNT(hs.job)>0 then #STD else #RED end) AS Colour,
       j.job, j.jobstatus, j.client, j.logdate
FROM jobs j INNER JOIN
     clients c
     ON c.client = j.client INNER JOIN
     holdsent hs
     ON hs.job = j.job
WHERE j.jobstatus in ('HOLD', 'CLIHOLD')
```

Comment: As the OP used `WHERE (jobs.jobstatus = 'HOLD' OR jobs.jobstatus = 'CLIHOLD')` shouldn't it be: `WHERE j.jobstatus IN ('HOLD', 'CLIHOLD')`

Comment: Wouldn't both of those be the same?